# How to insert data into table with lastID from previous insert in SQLite3 using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, rest

I have a RESTAPI on `express.js` and `node.js` to insert data into SQLite3 database.

The first insert is to add statement, and then retrieve the `lastID` to insert it to another table.

```
    router.post('/addStatement', function(req, res){

    const data = req.body;
    let corporate_statement_link_id = null;

    let statement_link_exist_query = `SELECT * FROM search_results WHERE company_id = ? and link = ?;`;
    let query = `INSERT INTO search_results (company_id, title, link, domain) VALUES(?,?,?,?)`
    let corp_query = `INSERT INTO corporate_statements (corporate_statement_link_id, corporate_statement) VALUES(?,?)`;
        
    db.all(statement_link_exist_query, [data.company_id, data.link], (err, row) => { 
        if (err){
            console.log('error: ', err)
            res.sendStatus(err.status).send(err);
        }

        if(row.length > 0){
            res.sendStatus(409).send("Link already exists");
        } 
        
        let insertStmt = db.prepare(query, [data.company_id, data.title, data.link, data.domain]);
        
        insertStmt.run(err => {
            if (err){
                console.log('error: ', err);
                res.sendStatus(err.status).send(err);
            }
            console.log("Last ID: ", insertStmt.lastID);
        
            let insertIDToScrapeData = db.prepare(corp_query, [insertStmt.lastID, 1]);
        
            insertIDToScrapeData.run(err => {
                if(err){
                    console.log('error: ', err);
                    res.sendStatus(err.status).send(err);
                }
                
            });

            corporate_statement_link_id = insertIDToScrapeData.lastID;
        });
        console.log("Scrape ID: ", corporate_statement_link_id);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(corporate_statement_link_id));
    });
    
 });
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: that's an error from ExpressJs telling you that you already sent data back (probably with `res.sendStatus()`) and you're doing it again, probably with the `res.send()`... try to send something back only once

Comment: @balexandre, that's the part I don't get. Cause it does't go to the error `res.sendStatus()`. I read in SO post which I can't find the link now, but it said something about inserting the data twice, and that's what's causing the error. But I do need to insert data in one table, and the get the id from inserted table to insert in another table.

Comment: but the error you are reporting has nothing to do with the database, I'm sure you didn't post the whole code... run in debug mode, hit that endpoint, and go through line by line to see what's going on. first thing you should do is change to `return res.status(...)` so it does not process anything else. Calling `res.status` or `res.send` does not stop the rest to be processed, you need to `return`

Comment: @balexandre, got it! Thank you for the clarifying it for me. It makes sense re-reading your comment now. I'll try that out.

Comment: now that you add `return` statements, what's is the new error?

Comment: @balexandre, that was illuminating. Turns out, I don't need .send() after res.sendStatus(). so that's why it was crashing. I fixed it by removing, and adding return as you suggested. It's working now. Thank you

Comment: see, it was nothing related to the database, just understand the error and you're good. happy programming! 